# What is the preferred method of ensuring that database objects are closed?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm curious about best practices when it comes to database interaction.  I've been using a pattern that I believe handles making sure all of the appropriate objects are closed when I'm done with them.  However, a coworker recently refactored my code with a comment along the lines of, "making sure we always close database objects".  I need to know if one pattern is "better" than the other for some reason. Is the pattern that I've been using wrong somehow?  Does one pattern have advantages over the other?

The pattern that I've been following:

```
public void doStuff() {
    try {
        final Connection connection = this.getConnection();

        try {
            final PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COLA, COLB FROM TBL WHERE COLC = ?");

            try {
                ps.setString(1, "asdf");
                final ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                try {
                    // get data from rs 
                } finally {
                    rs.close();
                }
            } finally {
                ps.close();
            }
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // do something with the error
    }
}
```

The pattern that my coworker modifed my code to:

```
public void doStuff() {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        connection = this.getConnection();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COLA, COLB FROM TBL WHERE COLC = ?");
        ps.setString(1, "asdf");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        // get data from rs
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // do something with the error
            }

        }
        if (ps!= null) {
            try {
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // do something with the error
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // do something with the error
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are right on looking again, your way also closes everything. I've retracted my answer:).   Both are butt ugly though.  If you have java7 than the try -with-resources is a vast improvement !

Comment: @RobertMoskal can't argue there! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Java 6 or prior, then use the latter because it's easier to read and maintain. Note that the latter can be improved with some refactoring to handle the cumbersome `try-catch` for every call to `close` method.

If you're using Java 7 or higher, then use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (Connection con = ...;
     PreparedStatement pstmt = ...) {
    pstmt.setXyz(...);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    //read data from resultset
    //and then close it
    rs.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //handle the exception properly...
}
```

In case you want to make sure about closing the `ResultSet`, you may use a nested `try-with-resources`:

```
try (Connection con = ...;
     PreparedStatement pstmt = ...) {
    pstmt.setXyz(...);
    try(ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
        //read data from resultset
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //handle the exception properly...
}
```

Comment: *Why* use the latter? What about it makes it better than the former?  try-with-resource is a great tip, though--thanks!

Comment: What if an exeption is thrown somewhere after the connect?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof it should be handled by the `catch` block. The `try-with-resources` will make sure to close the resources even if an exception was raised. You can find more info about it in the link I put on the post.

Comment: `rs.close()` may not be executed. (not that it matters in this API - con.close() takes care of it anyway)

Comment: If it's ok that `rs.close()` is not executed, why write it in the 1st place. Your code is not a fair demonstration of how much try-wtih-resource simplifies OP's code.

Comment: That's my point, you are missing one level of nesting as a fair demonstration of using try-with-resource for OP's problem

Answer (score 1):

The latter is easier to read; deep nesting is hard to reason about.

I prefer safe wrappers around closeables, e.g., they do nothing if the closeable is null. This also makes the mainline code easier to read.

Luigi's answer makes the most sense from Java 7 on,  of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's often simpler and cleaner to abstract the closure of your database resources to a dedicated manager object, which will contain any NPE's and such that might be thrown.

A pretty well written one exists as part of the open source project, OpenFire:

https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/master/src/java/org/jivesoftware/database/DbConnectionManager.java#L243

Sample helper method from this DbConnectionManager:

```
public static void closeResultSet(ResultSet rs) {
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
                rs.close();
            }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

So in your `finally` block you just pass your resources back into your manager, and it handles the ugly logic to test for nulls and catch exceptions, etc.

Like:

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    con = DbConnectionManager.getConnection();
    ps = con.prepareStatement(yourStatement);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if (rs != null) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    DbConnectionManager.closeConnection(rs, ps, con);
}
```

Comment: In this case, the connection won't be closed, and you will have a memory leak. In case you store the `Connection` somewhere, you will (somewhat) fall in the second piece of code provided by OP.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza this was quick sample code -- not deserving of a downvote. Updated to show better form. Should note, this connection comes from a pool manager as-to avoid the massive overhead of opening a new database connection on every method call.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza fair enough. thanks for un-down voting. ;-P

Comment: With try-with-resources there should be no need to use these types of hacks.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ARM blocks only work on J7+. There are plenty of systems out there that are still J6 and below.

Answer (score -5):

Simulating Go's defer statement :D

```
try(Defer defer = new Defer())
{
    Connection connection = ...;
    defer.add( connection::close );

    ....

    Path tmpFile = ...;
    defer.add( ()->Files.delete(tmpFile) );

    ....

} // Defer.close() => executing registered actions, from last to first
```

How `Defer` is implemented is left as an exercise to readers:)

Comment: What's the definition of `Defer` class in Java? I cannot find it in the JDK.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - none. it's an idea; the implementation should be trivial.

Comment: Then this isn't a proper answer.

Comment: Do you have to be so literal? :)

Comment: Currently, your post is only a recomendation of how other programming language may solve this and a bunch of uncompilable code. It's incomplete. Think on future readers, specially those readers that are starting to code and in Java (don't ask for details why they start with Java and not with Python or another PL). They will read this code and try to make it compile, and after some time they will realize they cannot do it. At least leave a proper message explaining the basic ideas of how to implement this. And it's not about being literal but explaining our ideas, nobody can read your mind.

Comment: they'll read the comments and understand, thanks to your 1st query.